# Interface splitter

Tags: c#, mocking, moq

I am mocking in this sort of situation:

```
class A
{
    public IB B {get; set;}
}

interface IB
{
  //methods
}

class B : IB
{
  //IB methods
}

public SimpleMockTest()
{
   var mockIB = new Mock<IB>();
   var a = new A{B=mockIB.Object};
   //do stuff with A, then verify methods on IB were called       
}

public TheKindOfTestIWantToDo()
{
   var actualB = new B();
   var mockIB = new Mock<IB>();
   var splitter = new Splitter<IB>(actualB, mockIB.Object); //I need something like this
   var a = new A{B=splitter};
   //do stuff with A, methods invoked on splitter IB get passed to both supplied instances
   //of IB (actualB, and the mockIB). Allowing me to verify the calls as well as have the methods invoked on the actual B object.
   //OR:
   var mockIB2 = new Mock<IB>(actualB); //behaviour is dictated by the actual, but allows verification
   var a2 = new A{B=mockIB2.Object};
}
```

So I am after some sort of proxy factory that would genericly support an interface and call the same method on multiple interfaces. Of course where a method returns a value, each would need to return the same value, or maybe one takes precident.

I want to effectively snoop on interface calls during the test, but without the mock being the end of the line.

Am using Moq if it makes any difference.

Comment: please explain this more ? "I want to effectively snoop on interface calls during the test, but without the mock being the end of the line."

Comment: @MicahArmantrout object A calls methods on B via the interface IB. I wanted to verify those calls whilst still having them invoked on B.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't a way to do this for all methods on `actualB`.

I think you want something like:

```
public TheKindOfTestIWantToDo()
{
   var actualB = new B();
   var mockIB = new Mock<IB>();
   mockIB.Setup(b => b.Foo()).Returns(() => actualB.Foo())
   var a = new A { B = mockIB };
   //do stuff with A, methods invoked on splitter IB get passed to both supplied instances
   //of IB (actualB, and the mockIB). Allowing me to verify the calls as well as have the methods invoked on the actual B object.
}
```

You should probably rethink your unit testing strategy, though.  The behavior of `A` should be testable without relying on the behavior of `B`.  Try having `mockIB` return specific values, and then write a different set of tests for `B`.

Comment: I agree with Steve. Your tests should not rely on the implementation of your dependencies.

Comment: Yeah, I have tests for A and B on their own, so I see where you are coming from on that. Is it bad to have tests for A and B working together though? I should just not try to test the internal communications between them? Just black-box those 2 as a single component.

Comment: In that case, you are doing an integration test, and I don't see a reason why you should need to ensure that any particular methods were actually called, since you should have asserted that in the unit tests.